# How to escalate kubernetes container privileges for pod securityContext runAsUser: 1010

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I have pod level security context like in below snippet:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1010
    runAsGroup: 1010
    fsGroup: 1010
  containers:
       --------
       -------
```

one of my container need root privileges so I added one more securityContext as below:

```
   spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1010
        runAsGroup: 1010
        fsGroup: 1010
      containers:
      - name: sample
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        image: sampleimage
        ----------------
        -----------------
```

Now my container is able to run with root privileges but my requirement is rather than making **runAsUser: 0** which is root! Is there any other way we can escalate privileges for container alone using same **runAsUser: 1010**  ?

I found some options like **allowPrivilegeEscalation:** true & **capabilities:** but no luck! maybe am using it in wrong way.

```
containers:
- image: sampleimage
  name: sample
  securityContext:
    allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
```

AND

```
  containers:
  - image: sampleimage
    name: sample
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add: ["SYS_ADMIN"]
```

Can anyone help by correcting my code or help with an example to refer to and implement? Please.

Comment: Can you clarify your issue a little bit?  It seems like specifying `runAsUser: 0` allows your process to run as root; is that what you want?

Comment: @David Maze Yes specifying runAsUser:0 sorted out my issue!! but rather than giving runAsUser:0 keeping runAsUser:1010 pod level can we elevate privileges for the container? without changing userid to 0 (runAsUser:0)

Comment: Please tell how exactly are you trying to test that you have specific privileges? Do you have the Admission Controller enabled in the cluster? Do you have any `PSP` created?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the appropriate capabilities for the action you want to permit for the container.

As described in the 
[kubernetes official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#capabilities)

There are 7 capabilities that you can choose from [linux documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

And everything comes down to what privileges you want to grant to the specific user.

> Example

Confirm that you pass the correct configuration by running the following commands

`kubectl exec pod -c container whoami`

`kubectl exec -it pod -c container -- date -s '10 APR 2020 10:10:10'`

With the second command if you specified something wrong you will receive the error

date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted

Now if you add the Capability SYS_TIME

```
  containers:
  - image: yourimage
    name: yourimagename
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 1010
      capabilities:
        add: ["SYS_TIME"]
```

Execute the second command again and you will see the date reflected as string.

Comment: but capability SYS_ADMIN not giving access inside the container as of root eg: not able to create a new directory inside /root folder of the container for user 1010

Comment: Please check this issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77986 someone used fsGroup: 1024 for a similar situation. You should also have in mind that CAP_SYS_ADMIN: Allows a wide range of operations. This capability should be avoided in favor of more specific capabilities.